# IE 9 still posts back when user cancels operation with JavaScript button

Tags: javascript, asp.net, internet-explorer-9, asp.net-4.5

I have this simple image button in a gridview.  When a user clicks on it, it should warn the user before performing a delete.  It has no problem if the user clicks 'OK' at the prompt, but when the user clicks 'Cancel', the page still performs a postback and deletes the record.

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="btnRemove" runat="server" ImageUrl"~/Images/btnRemove.gif" CommandName="Delete" OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure?');">
```

It works fine in IE8 and Firefox but doesn't work in IE9.

Comment: which ASP.NET version is this?

Comment: Using Visual Studio 2012 with framework 4.5